# Can OCI_CONNECT cause a ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column?

Tags: php, oracle, ora-01438

I'm wondering if oci_connect() can cause a 1438 error, because i get this all the time:

> Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: ORA-00604: error
>   occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01438: value larger than
>   specified precision allowed for this column ORA-06512: at line 8 in
>   /xxxxxx/some.php on line 220

It's not depending on which table is being queried. It seems like oci_connect() is inserting some trackingstaff in some sys table, or maybe a trigger is related with the logon. But i don't have the permission to figure out this problem in sys.

Any Idea what could be the cause for this error?

**Update**

Does oracle do some logging somewhere automatically out of box without configured to specifically? Can i somehow let oracle or PHP show me which table or column is affected?

**Update**
I found out that, when i call the PHP Script in Bash directly, it does work fine. But a call from web will cause titled problem. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `error occurred at recursive SQL level 1` suggests to me that the error is arising within a trigger.  My guess is that there is an `AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA` or `DATABASE` trigger, and for some reason it causes an error when your web server process attempts to connect.

Here's an example of how to generate the error you're getting.  I have a table called `TINY`, with a single column that can only take values up to 99:

```
SQL> desc tiny;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 N                                                  NUMBER(2)
```

Now let's create a user account and verify that they can connect:

```
SQL> create user fred identified by fred account unlock;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to fred;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect fred/fred
Connected.
```

Good - let's log back in as me and create a trigger that will cause an error if `FRED` attempts to connect:

```
SQL> connect luke/password
Connected.
SQL> create or replace trigger after_logon_error_if_fred
  2    after logon on database
  3  begin
  4    if user = 'FRED' then
  5      insert into tiny (n) values (100);
  6    end if;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Recall that our `TINY` table can only store values up to 99.  So, what happens when `FRED` attempts to connect?

```
SQL> connect fred/fred
ERROR:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Other than the line number, and the bit PHP added, that's exactly the message you got.

If you want to see whether there are any `AFTER LOGON` triggers in your database, try running the query

```
SELECT trigger_name, owner FROM all_triggers
 WHERE TRIM(triggering_event) = 'LOGON';
```

On my database (Oracle 11g XE beta), I get the following output:

```
TRIGGER_NAME                   OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------
AFTER_LOGON_ERROR_IF_FRED      LUKE
```

I don't believe Oracle does any logging out-of-the-box, and I'd be surprised if PHP's `oci_connect` does either.

I can only speculate as to why the error arises only for your web server and not when you run PHP from a  bash script.  Perhaps the trigger is querying `V$SESSION` and trying to figure out what user account is trying to connect to the database?

Comment: Sounds great! I'll try to get this information from the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on the column, you're either trying to insert a number that's larger than the allowed bounds for a `numeric` column, or you're trying to insert a string into a `varchar2(n)` column that is longer than `n` characters.  [Here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm) are more specifics on Oracle datatypes.

Without more specific information as to what's being inserted into what column in what table at line 220 of `some.php`, I can't be of much more direct help.

Comment: `ORA-01438` only happens with numeric columns. If you try to insert a value too large for a `varchar2` column it gives you `ORA-12899: value too large for column`